# Size of a Conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is this true that a group (not necessarily finite) that has a conjugacy class of size 4 or 5 is not simple?

I know from part of Burnside theorem (its proof actually) that a finite simple group does not have a conjugacy class of order that is a prime power. But I want to know if it is true in general or the size 4 is special. (If possible I appreciate an explanation not using character theory and representation since I have just started to study the subject and not very good at it).

Comment: This is not hard to prove. Any such group has a nontrivial homomorphism to $S_4$ or $S_5$. So the only candidate would be $A_5$, but that has no conjugacy class of order $5$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt, thanks, would you please explain little further. Lets say we only know that there is conjugacy class of size 4. How can we show it has a  nontrivial normal subgroup in this way?

Comment: In its conjugation action, the group  $G$  is permuting the four elements in this class. So we have a nontrivial  homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_4$. If $G$ was simple then $\phi$ would have trivial kernel, and so $G$ would be isomorphic to a nontrivial subgroup of $S_4$, and then $G$ clearly cannot be simple.

Comment: @ Derek Holt, Thanks, got it. Was going in the wrong direction. You may wanna post it as an answer so I can accept it.